# Selenium Webdriver asserting code after JQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium

I have a span area, which holds a sum.

```
  <span id="total">
   0
   </span>
```

This sum is calculated in jquery function, firing when user launches onclick events on checkbox elements.

```
    function toggleSum (param) {
       if (param.checked) {
        $("#total").text(param.dataset['addsum']);
        sum = parseFloat(param.dataset['addsum']);
```

I am writing Selenium webdriver tests and wondering if there is someway to assert the sum after the driver has been "clicking" it to its final amount.

Comment: Are you using junit or testng?

Comment: you just need to know the two numbers you're adding and assert that the value inside the span, where id="total", is equal to the expected value..

Comment: I think I can't do it simply with webdriver by locating the element (driver.findelement(By.id), because the sum does not update to the source code.

Comment: @mjgirl then what `$("#total").text(param.dataset['addsum']);` is doing?